# How to find 2nd element with the same class as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a table with most of first cells in tr having first cell with the same value in a different tr. I'm going to use these for tr identification. Eventually, I want tds in these trs interact in a few diferent ways between themselves (pull data one and append into a different td, make calculations based on the data, etc). But for a start, I need all the doubled tr's have text the same color

html

```
<div class="tableclass">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>id1</td>
       <td>something else</td>
       <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>id2</td>
       <td>something else</td>
       <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>id2</td>
       <td>something else</td>
       <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>id3</td>
       <td>something else</td>
       <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>id1</td>
       <td>something else</td>
       <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
  </table>
<div>
```

and jquery

```
$(".tableclass table tbody tr").each(function(){
           var trclass = $(this).find("td:first-child").html();
           $(this).addClass(trclass);
           $(this).parent().filter(trclass).eq(2).css('color','red');

});
```

And obviously, i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Although your question is not clear enough, But I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11772742/1908331) can help you get some idea on how to implement this duplicate content detecting...

Comment: I got detecting duplicate content detection working fine. I'm having trouble finding another tr with same class, based on variable.

Comment: @shakhar, Please be careful when you edit a post. the selected tag that you had deleted was `JavaScript` not `java` and `JavaScript` is totally related to this question...

Comment: please post relevant html so we can better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: So then please edit your post and elaborate more on your situation and add more code of your html or a sample html table with data and on that sample table describe what is your desire...

Comment: added more info

Comment: OK, good. and please explain what are you looking for in this data and what should be the output of your JavaScript code? as I can see in this line `var trclass = $(this).find("td:first-child").html();` you are getting the content of the first cell of the row and storing it in `trclass`. the at next line you are using this content as a `css class`!!! Why?

Comment: Because i want to find another tr with that same class and do something with it. In this instance, to change a color. Later, i'll be adding equations for number values, and appending text values to different places. So, I need some kind of selector for that. But for now, It's just to change color.

Comment: @EhsanT, this is really weird. It was tagged as java. I even have the old page loaded in one of my browser tabs. However, the revision history is not showing java anywhere.

Comment: @Shakhar I've accidently used java tag, but changed it really quickly

Comment: Maybe, we were doing it at the same time. I do remember removing java and not javascript.

Comment: OK, I have a question for you, what if there were more than one duplicate element. Do you have such condition or you may only have 0 or 1 duplicate element of any given element?

Comment: 1 is the max of duplicate element. Btw, I've also posted a question about what i want to do after this. May be it will make more sense http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497579/get-a-value-out-of-element-with-same-variable-class

Comment: I think I have the solution for you, Please let me know you want to continue this question or the other one? And which ever you choose, Please delete the other question. and try not to post duplicate question since they may get flagged.

Comment: Let's do the 2nd one. I'll delete this one.

Comment: I have solution to mark all 'duplicates', but reading your second question... not sure that it will help (and that you actually need it)... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var rows = $(".tableclass tbody tr");
var iterations = 0;
var rowNo = 0;
rows.each(function () {
    var thisRow = $(this);
    rowNo++;
    if (!thisRow.hasClass('duplicate')) {
        var trclass = thisRow.find("td:first-child").html();
        var firstcols = thisRow.siblings('tr').find('td:first-child');
        firstcols.each(function () { 
            if ($(this).html() == trclass) {
                var dupeRow = $(this).parent();
                var dupeRowNo = dupeRow.index() + 1;
                thisRow
                   .addClass('duplicate')
                   .css({'color': 'red'})
                   .attr('title', 'Duplicated in row '+dupeRowNo);
                dupeRow
                  .addClass('duplicate')
                  .css({'color': 'red'})
                  .attr('title', 'Duplicate of row '+rowNo);
                iterations++;
            }       
        })
    }
});
//alert(iterations);
```

It is a little more compicated, but it identifies the duplicate rows without having to go through the each row twice. I added the `iterations` variable so you can see that it only goes and processes a `tr` if it has not already identified it before as having duplicates.

I added tooltips to the rows so you know which row is a duplicate of which.

You can see it on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5nwuybz6/2/).