# Get a value out of element with same variable class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Posted a similar question, but may be this case will make more sense. Got a table with many first td's of tr having a duplicate first td in a different tr. I'm using these for identification. I want to pull a value from 2nd tr and insert it into already appended(!) td in the first tr. Here is a quick html code example

```
<div class="tableclass">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>id1</td>
       <td>something else</td>
       <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>id2</td>
       <td>something else</td>
       <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>id2</td>
       <td>something else</td>
       <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>id3</td>
       <td>something else</td>
       <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>id1</td>
       <td>something else</td>
       <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
  </table>
<div>
```

And here is my jquery code

```
$(".tableclass table tbody tr").each(function(){
  $(this).append('<td class="fbctr"></td>');
   var trclass = $(this).find("td:first-child").html();
   $(this).addClass(trclass);
   // this is where I'm having a problem
   var fbctr = $(this).parent().filter(trclass).eq(2).find("td:nth-child(3)");
   $(this).find(".fbctr").html(fbctr);
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to get there? What is the expected value of `fbctr`?

Comment: So basically you want to get the content of the 3rd cell of the row with duplicate class and copy it in the child element with `fbctr` class of current row?

Comment: Is [this simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1n69fwt/) what you are looking for?

Comment: @EhsanT yes. Though, when i substituted that problematic line with $(this).parent().find('tr').filter('.'+trclass).eq(1).find('td:nth-child(3)'); i got  "jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ." error for jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, your problem is that `jquery` `.filter()` works on a set of given DOM elements. So you have to first select `<tr>` elements and then use `.filter()`. In your question you are applying it on your `<table>`

So, Your JavaScript code will be like this:

```
$(".tableclass table tbody tr").each(function(){
    var trclass = $(this).find("td:first-child").html();
    $(this).addClass(trclass);
    var fbctr = $(this).parent().find('tr').filter('.'+trclass).eq(1).find("td:nth-child(3)").html();
    if(typeof fbctr !== "undefined"){
        console.log(fbctr);
        $(this).find(".fbctr").html(fbctr);
    } 
});
```

**Update(Corrected Code):**

In case you want to copy the value of **first** occurring element into the **second** occurring element, use this code:

```
$(".tableclass table tbody tr").each(function(){
    var trclass = $(this).find("td:first-child").html();
    $(this).addClass(trclass);
    var elements = $(this).parent().find('tr').filter('.'+trclass);
    if(elements.length > 1){
      var fbctr = elements.eq(0).find("td:nth-child(3)").html();
      if(typeof fbctr !== "undefined")
        $(this).find(".fbctr").html(fbctr);
    }
});
```

And in case you want to copy the value of **second** occurring element into the **first** occurring element, use this code:

```
$(".tableclass table tbody tr").each(function(){
    var trclass = $(this).find("td:first-child").html();
    $(this).addClass(trclass);
    var elements = $(this).parent().find('tr').filter('.'+trclass);
    var fbctr = elements.eq(1).find("td:nth-child(3)").html();
    if(typeof fbctr !== "undefined")
        $('.'+trclass).not(this).find(".fbctr").html(fbctr);
});
```

Comment: This way, It's inserting the value into the same tr it got the value from

Comment: OK, then you want to replace the content of the first element with the second or vice versa? Maybe we can take another approach...

Comment: I want to pull info from the 2nd tr and place it into added td in the first tr.

Comment: @hahna, Just updated my answer, You can use either of the options depending on your need

Comment: :) you are welcome...

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the duplicate rows first and remove all the duplicate rows but not first, then in the first rows append the 3rd td element of the last duplicate row.

In the below solution i am also removing the duplicate rows, you can keep/remove that based on your requirement.

Here is the working solution where i have added few extra node for testing of the solution.

```js
var rows = $(".tableclass table tbody tr")
rows.each(function() {
  var trclass = $(this).find("td:first-child").html();
  $(this).addClass(trclass);
  var dupeRows = rows.filter("." + trclass);
  rows.filter("." + trclass).not(":first").remove();
  if (dupeRows.length > 1) {
    rows.filter("." + trclass).first().append('<td>' + $(dupeRows[dupeRows.length - 1]).find("td:nth-child(3)").html() + '</td>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tableclass">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>id1</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>id2</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>id2</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>id3</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>id1</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>id2</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>id2</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    ;
```

Comment: @hahna was this helpful?